# API request shows correct response in Chrome DevTools but is actually null in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, frontend

My app is supposed to display Code Analysis logs. Those logs are in large(20k+ lines) html files. I'm reading them in ASP.NET Core app and pass them as string to API. C# read them nicely and passes them on, Chrome shows the correct response in DevTools, and yet Angular doesn't seem to notice this and logs null to the console aswell as when I try to display them.

I'm relatively new to Angular so I might be ommiting something obvious here. Here's my code - that's the Get method that reads and passes the file:

```
    [HttpGet, Route("analysis")]
    public string Analysis(string projectName, string definitionName)
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(@"\\glbuild2\CodeAnalysisLogs", projectName, definitionName, "CodeAnalysis.html");
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
        {
            string temp = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
            return temp;
        }
        else return "Error";
    }
```

And here's the method I use to make an API request(please note it does work, I use the same method with different uri but to the same server and it works there):

```
    this.http.get('http://localhost:54639/api/logs/analysis?projectName=' + this.currentDefinition.project.name + '&definitionName=' + this.currentDefinition.name).subscribe(data => {
      this.AnalysisLogs = data;
      console.log(data);
    })
```

Now the line logging to console always logs null, and the response in DevTools is the one I'm expecting: a string going

Comment: Is the API and HTML making the call are from same origin?

Comment: @Ramesh both apps are in debug, ASP.NET Core from Visual Studio Express 2015 and Angular from VS Code, but all my API calls are to this server and it worked perfectly this far. If you mean the localhost adress, no, they're on different ports.